# error of symbol not available in ot1

Tags: symbols

I'm writing a manuscript for an Elsevier journal, and when I try to type in a per mille sign using \textperthousand an error comes up saying command \textperthousand unavailable in encoding OT1. Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to T1-encoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\textperthousand 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the text companion fonts:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{textcomp}
 \begin{document}
 \textperthousand
 \end{document}
```

Advantage over the T1 fonts: In the text companion fonts there is a ready-made `\textperthousand`, it will also work in typewriter fonts.